# Program to switch between two concurrently playing music tracks

Tags: audio, music

I'm DM-ing a group and want to introduce a somewhat dynamically shifting music track for combat where it would change from a "planning stage" theme to an "action stage" at the press of a button and vise versa, similar to what you would see in turn-based RPGs. With that in mind I'm looking for a program where I can load both of those themes and switch between them when I needed.

OS should be either Windows or iOS. Sound format preferably .mp3 but can convert to other formats. As for price I can't think of a number as I want to see all of the possibilities before I make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a couple solutions myself.

**Solution A:** Use VLC Player to open the second track on top of the first as a separate audio track in [Media > Open Multiple Files > Play Another Media Synchronously] then switch them around in [Audio > Audio Track]. (Produces a bit of delay as the switch happens)

**Solution B:** Use Audacity to mix tracks together into one, where one track is on the left channel and the other is on the right, and use sound balance controls in a media player to shift from one to the other. (In my case it made the sound fuzzy, but that could just be VLC acting up and results may vary on other players)

Overall I found Solution A to be the one I would personally use.

Answer (score 0):

I think any DJ software would be suited for your case. I remember that Virtual DJ is somewhat easy for beginners with auto fading between both tracks on the right BPM.

If you want gapless playback and don't need fades between tracks or BPM sync, Foobar2000 would certainly serve your need, already.